# SpringBoot which application.properties is used (runtime)

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-logback

there are several options where the application.properties/ application.yaml can be located:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.external-config.files

If someone make a mistake and add a application.properties to a dependent JAR it is automatically found in classpath. This can cause some strange behaviour of the application.

I search for an option/ solution to get all *used* application.properties/ application.yaml at current application context. I want to log this information.

Is there a possiblity to inject the used property files into a bean?

Thanks and best regards, Oli

Answer (score 0):

You can activate Spring Boot actuator by adding this dependency:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

and use its `configprops` endpoint to show all properties currently used by the application:

```
https://localhost:8080/actuator/configprops
```